# Checking available dates - LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I have 2 tables from my database 'Cars' & 'Booking' In the 'Car' table I have these properties: CarID(PK), Make, Model and Size. In the 'Booking' table: ID(PK), CarID(FK), StartDate & EndDate.

I have a WPF application with 3 pieces of user inputted information: Car Size, Start Date and End Date. The user inputs this information and clicks a button triggering a query to search through the database and find cars that are the same size and available on the dates that the user has selected.

I have entered values for all properties of the database through SQL Server Management Studio.

My question: I have figured out how to search for the car size but I don't understand how to search the database from the start of the date to the end.

This is how I have made the date picker in the XAML code of the WPF:

```
    <StackPanel Margin="125,56,264,279.4">
        <DatePicker Margin="0,0,10.2,0" Height="25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This is my query so far:

```
var searchQuery = from c in db.Cars
           join b in db.Bookings on c.CarID equals b.CarID
           where c.Size == comboBox_CarType.Text
           && EndDate.SelectedDate < b.EndDate && StartDate.SelectedDate > 
           b.StartDate
           select c.Make.Trim() + " - " + c.Model.Trim();


            listBox_AvailableCars.ItemsSource = searchQuery.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var searchQuery = from c in db.Cars
                  join b in db.Bookings on c.CarID equals b.CardID
                  where c.Size == comboBox_CarType.Text 
                  && datepicker.SelectedDate < b.EndDate && datepicker.SelectedDate > b.StartDate
                  select c.Make.Trim() + " - " + c.Model.Trim();

listBox_AvailableCars.ItemsSource = searchQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: The datepicker.value does not work. datepicker does not contain a definition for 'value'

Comment: You haven't named the control in the example I just gave an example. When I say datepicker.value I mean the value from your control whatever it is

Comment: I think it has a selecteddate try that

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean give the each datepicker a name, is the right?

Comment: Yes without giving name how can you access it, you gave name to combobox right ?

Comment: Yeah, the combo box and both datepickers now have names, I have edited the code above to show what I now have as you suggested however it is not showing anything in the listbox

Comment: Can you check the query in profiler and see if that works from sql management studio

Comment: I cant run the profiler from my college database as I dont have admin rights

Comment: Okay just debug and see date and check database for same dates, see if you see any records

Comment: Sure thing, I will look over the debug list and come back when I have some more info, thanks

Comment: Okay, so I dont know for sure but one thing I did notice is that on the SQL Server Managment the date formation is YYYY/MM/DD and in the DatePicker its DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: I don't think that matters as long as the column is a DateTime column, can you check column data type?

Comment: I have the datatype in the SQL Server set to date, Im assuming I should change tht to the dateTime now that you've said it

Comment: Then the above code works ? Please debug and see the dates from date picker and try to run query in management studio

Comment: I think I just got it, in the code you suggested you were using the && symbol for both start and end Date, I've tried it with the || (or) and it has given out the results I expected

Comment: How come || work, you want the car date should be in between start and end right

Comment: Yeah I noticed that again, I need to go over the database and make sure there are no incorrect data types, sorry for the hassle, Im gonna make your answer right as the logic does make perfect sense. Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: Good you got it. Happy coding!